# Ember 2 action sent to route instead of component

Tags: ember.js

In my app I've defined this component:

```
// components/buy-functions.js
export default Ember.Mixin.create({
    actions: {
        openModal: function() {
            $('#buyModal').openModal();
        }
    }
});
```

then in the route's template:

```
<h5>Buy form</h5>
{{#buy-functions}}
    <div class="btn" {{action "openModal"}}>Buy</div>
{{/buy-functions}}
```

(the component does not have a template)

But when i click the button I get the error "nothing handled the "openModal" action... 
Can someone explain what I'm doing wrong here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to send your action to route

```
 openModal: function(modalName) {
          this.sendAction('openModal',modalName);
            }
        }
```

change your button to

```
<div class="btn" {{action "openModal" 'myModal'}}>Buy</div>
```

and then in your route

```
openModal: function(modalName) {
            //do whatever you want 
        }
```

But another way would be:

let's change your component to

```
// components/buy-functions.js
export default Ember.Component.extend({
    actions: {
        openModal: function() {
            $('#buyModal').openModal();
        }
    }
});
```

then create your component template

```
 // tempaltes/components/buy-functions.hbs
    <div class="btn" {{action "openModal"}}>Buy</div>
```

and then in your route template only use your component name

```
{{buy-functions}}
```

I wrote these codes on the fly. hope it works for you.

Comment: Ok so components needs to have a template in order to use their own actions?

Comment: Yeap otherwise you need to sendAction to route

Comment: @CerealKiller a component without a template is a tiny bit useless.

Comment: @Lux I have many component without templates in my app, they are more versatile since you can define the behaviour in terms of js code in the component and the template directly in the HTML which means you can reuse the component with different HTML inside of it; this was just the first time I was using such a component with actions, normally in components without a template I just use the didInsertElement hook to activate some javascript

Comment: @CerealKiller this seems like a big antipattern to be honest! `didInsertElement` is really mostly just for compatibility with legacy JS code.

Comment: @Lux Yes that's the main use of it... but in ember it's the only way I've found to properly activate external js plugins

Answer (score 1):

There is an add-on ([ember-route-action-helper](https://www.npmjs.com/package/ember-route-action-helper)) that provides a helper (route-action) for just this very use case.

There's a [blog about it](https://dockyard.com/blog/2016/02/19/best-practices-route-actions).